# Specify fields to exclude from Rails query result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

To select specific fields for the result of a query, you can use the `select` method:

```
Client.select(:name)
```

This returns a relation of Clients where the `name` is the only field initialized.

**I'd like to select all fields, except for the ones I specify.** Exactly like select, but the inverse.

```
Client.select(name: false) # Hypothetical! Not real!
```

The above hypothetical would return a relation of Clients with all fields initialized, except the `name`.

Obviously, that hypothetical example does not work. Is there anything that would?

Constraints: I'd like to do this entirely within the domain of the ActiveRecord/SQL — I do not want to convert to Ruby arrays or hashes.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know who downvoted or why, but this is a great question along with a great answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use:

```
Client.select(Client.column_names - ["name", "some_other_column"])
```

Edit: Rails 5 also introduced `ignored_columns` if you want to exclude columns by default.

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/21720
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-ignored_columns-3D

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!